# what about saving extra variable in a QuerySet?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

for example i have a queryset say `folder=Folder.objects.all()`.

what about saving some extra variable in it say

```
for i in folder:
    i.fcount = 33
```

so that i can use it in templates easily like:

```
{% for folder in folders %}{{ folder.fcount }}{% endfor %}
```

I am using like this in one of my page:

#### models.py

```
class Folder(models.Model):
    employer=models.ForeignKey(Employer)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)    
    lastupdate= models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class SavedCandidateManager(models.Manager):
    def itemcount(self,fd):
        return self.filter(folder=fd).count()    

class SavedCandidate(models.Model):
    folder=models.ForeignKey(Folder)    
    candidate=models.ForeignKey(Jobseeker)
    created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    objects=SavedCandidateManager()
```

#### views.py

```
def folder(request):

    folder=Folder.objects.filter(employer=request.user.employer)
    for i in folder:
        i.fcount=SavedCandidate.objects.itemcount(i)
    return render(request,'employer/pages/candidatefolder.html', {'folders':folder})
```

#### candidatefolder.html

```
 {% for folder in folders %}
<tr>
    <td>         
        <a href="/Folder/{{ folder.id }}/" >{{ folder.name }}</a>            
    </td>
    <td>{{ folder.fcount }}</td>
    <td>{{ folder.lastupdate }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

this is very helpful since i can use it in templates easily in forloop look:

```
{{ folder.fcount }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always can use the extra method, like this:

```
folder=Folder.objects.all().extra(select = {'fcount':33})
```

So, for each f in your folder queryset you will have some fcount property.

It works like an SQL Alias.

If you want to use with some other data based on your model you have to use annotate(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate), maybe with a custom aggregation function(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/).

Comment: thanks its is nice i used `folder=Folder.objects.filter(employer=request.user.employer).extra(
  select={
   'entry_count': 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM candidatefolder_savedcandidate WHERE candidatefolder_savedcandidate.folder_id = candidatefolder_folder.id'
   },
  )`